# How do I feed a list of integers into SQL and it returns a dataframe of items

Tags: r

```
example <- c(1:100)

example_line <- paste0( "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = ", example)
example_df <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn=con, statement = example_line)
```

I've tried the above & it returns an error - expecting a single string value

was wanting a data frame of data from TABLE instead...

Comment: How does the error look, please supply us more data. Either textual or a screenshot. Also I think this is not the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `in`:

```
example <- c(1:10)
example_line <- paste0( "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id in (", paste0(example,collapse=','),")")
example_line
[1] "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)"
```